# How to claim network cards after unbinded from DPDK?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, dpdk

We're using [Intel DPDK](http://dpdk.org/) at work, however, sometimes binded network cards are needed "in system".
After I unbing some of them (let's say, 2/4) with `./dpdk-devbind -u (deviceID here)` they aren't binded to DPDK, but I cannot assign them IP addresses in Ubuntu.
Performing `ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0` returns `No such device found: eth0` (I'm 100% sure that `eth0` is that needed network card, btw)

So when I type `lshw -class network` it returns something like that:

  `*-network:0 UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Ethernet Controller XL710 for 40GbE QSFP+
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress vpd cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b9800000-b9ffffff memory:ba818000-ba81ffff memory:bba80000-bbafffff memory:ba600000-ba7fffff memory:ba9a0000-baa1ffff`

How can I claim these unbinded network cards **without rebooting the machine**? It's very important not to reboot that server since it's used by many people at once.

I tried executing `modprobe i40e` to load network module, it doesn't help. Obviously restarting networking service (via systemd) doesn't work as well, since these network cards are unclaimed and "hidden" somehow from system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, what I do is the following:

```
./dpdk-devbind.py -u <device_ID>
./dpdk-devbind.py -b <driver> <device_ID>
```

Indeed, you need to rebind it back to its driver.
In your case:

```
./dpdk-devbind.py -b i40e <device_ID>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed! Unfortunately I didn't pay attention to "unused" section of `dpdk-devbind -s` output, which said which options to bind (kernel & dpdk in my case) are available.